# ImportError: 'useNavigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When trying to import `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom`, I get the following error:

```sh
Attempted import error: 'useNavigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

**My Import statement:**

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: which doc are you referring ? [react router dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) or [react router dom github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom). Neither of them are having `useNavigate`. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @SagarMore i am trying to navigate to the next screen

Comment: @SagarMore documentation:``` In v6, this app should be rewritten to use the navigate API. Most of the time this means changing useHistory to useNavigate and changing the history.push or history.replace callsite.

// This is a React Router v6 app
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate('/home')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>go home</button>
    </div>
  );
}```

Comment: i guess then, you might have to check if you have installed/using correct version of react-router-dom. Have you installed using this ?

`npm install react-router-dom@next`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to use the latest features of `react-router`.
Please make sure that you installed the `react-router-dom@6.0.0-alpha.2` .

> It is **React Router v6** which gives you a useNavigate hook

Please [refer here for further reading from the React Router team](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/)

Two quick ways to check the version:

- Verify from the `package.json` file
- Run `npm list --depth=0` to view the various packages in your project

Answer (score 12):

If you're using react router v5 you can use useHistory.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

use:

```
history.push('/your-component')
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced issue as like this: "**useNavigate is not exported from 'react-router-dom**"

**My solution**  - I uninstalled the react-router-dom and I have reinstalled it... now this issue is resolved for me..